# Library from jre\lib\ext not found on the classpath

Tags: java, maven, javafx, shared-libraries, classpath

I have created application in JavaFX which interact with smartcards (via class `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11` located at `jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar`). The program runs and works well when maven `jfx:run` goal (of `javafx-maven-plugin` plugin) is executed.

Unfortunately after creating jar archive (using `jfx:jar` goal) and running the result jar. Application throws an exception at startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 12 more
```

I have found simple workaround for this problem by installing `sunpkcs11.jar` locally to maven and adding dependency in project pom file. Such solution is, as I mentioned, "workaround" and looks ugly.

Why application cannot find library which is one of the "standard" ones? Is JavaFX jar using custom classloader which does not see this library?

Even when I create native bundle (.exe in my case) with its own `JRE` it cannot see that class.

**update**

The is not a duplicate of question linked in comment, I have 32 bit JDK and JRE. `JAVA_HOME` also points to 32bit JRE.

Comment: i Quess you have read the 1st paragraph  http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/jar-bundle.html

Comment: @AntJavaDev Thanks for answer, I have read this paragraph and I use `jfx:jar` goal (without `clean` due to complicated structure of projects). I am also running correct jar (from `target/jfx/app` directory).

Comment: yes i mean can you see if at the requested /lib folder exists your jar? cause if it doesnt exists means that maven isnt exporting it

Comment: I can see `lib/` directory. It resides in `target/jfx/app` and contains all project custom dependencies. However, it does not contain `sunpkcs11.jar` (unless I use workaround described in question) as this one is JRE library.

Comment: well i cant understand why its ugly for you to put it as dependency in pom (you dont have all other external project dependencies in there???), cause if you dont then it will not be exported after building the project and that's why you dont see it in the /lib folder

Comment: @ItachiUchiha - I have 32bit JDK. @AntJavaDev - That's quite easy - Every programmer has to invoke `mvn install:install-file (..)` before the first build of project. This library is included in every 32bit JDK, so there should not be need of installing it manually.

Comment: If you think that this is related with the javafx-maven, then [raise an issue with the javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/issues)

Comment: I think that this problem is not related to javafx-maven. It is probably about javafx classloader.

Comment: If are sure that there is feel free to raise an issue with the [JavaFX dev team](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/). Its free and easy to sign up !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. I've solved it by coping the security libraries into `lib` directory (using `maven-antrun-plugin` for that, but you can figure out your own way to do this).

You'll probably need to copy the `sunpkcs11.jar` file from your jre installation.

Comment: That's what I did. I described it as a workaround in the question :)

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski next step in solving this problem - I've stopped using `javafx-maven-plugin` and configured standard `maven-jar-plugin` to create an executable jar with dependencies.

Comment: It still does not solve the problem. This JAR is one of the standard ones. I do not have to put in the `lib\` directory JARs as `jfxrt.jar`, `rt.jar`. Why doesn't it fetch libs from JRE `ext` directory? That's why I think it is some kind of JavaFX classloader issue.